# How to get rid of cookie acceptance pop-up without accepting the cookies?

Tags: feature-request

It's really obtrusive and is totalitarian to have taking up half the page.

Do better!

Answer (score 5):

You don't. That's the whole point. You either accept the policies of the site or you don't use the site.

Comment: Obviously that's not true. I haven't accepted the cookies and I'm still using the site.

Comment: check your cookies.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/View-Cookies